# Class in vendors directory cannot access Yii 2 class

Tags: yii2, composer-php

I have a class in a directory **classes** in the root directory of a Yii 2 project. Let's call this class as `FirstClass`. It is namespaced as `app\classes`.

To accomplish a particular task, another class called `ApplicationProcessor` inside the vendor directory needs to instantiate `FirstClass`. However, `FirstClass` cannot be accessed. I tried passing `app\classes\FirstClass` to `ApplicationProcessor` but it doesn't work.

What should I pass to `ApplicationProcessor` so that it can locate the class in the root directory of the Yii 2 project?

Comment: Maybe off topic, but why should a vendor class access `FirstClass`, that is located in root folder? It could be vice versa, but not in the way you are asking..

Comment: It manages the running of ```FirstClass```. This actually works if I move ```FirstClass``` to the same directory as ```ApplicationProcessor``` but of course that is not an option.

Comment: any file, that is located inside "vendor" folder is called a third-party code, so it has no information about anything that is outside its scope. It can receive some sort of settings though configurations, but not direct class call. If this third-party library is your development, you have to implement it through settings, otherwise you can do nothing, as when you `composer update` you project, your changes will be reset.

Comment: @Yerke Yes. It seems that way. I'm a bit puzzled why the library is working that way. I'm not sure if I'm missing something or maybe I should just extend the classes that they have.

Comment: just copy the whole library into your project, change namespaces and use as you wish. I believe it will be the easiest solution for your problem

Comment: @Yerke Not really ideal as this would entail having to manually take into consideration updates to the library.